# Unplugged Trezor when incoming transaction was unconfirmed

Tags: synchronization, bip32-hd-wallets, trezor, lost-transactions

I transferred some bitcoins from one of my online wallet to my Trezor. When the transaction is in unconfirmed mode I unplugged my Trezor. Then after I plugin my Trezor that transaction somehow did not show up on my Trezor. Now what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If the transaction has confirmed, then there is nothing that you need to do. Your Trezor device does not actually receive the transaction nor does it need to. All that matters is that the wallet software that you are using knows about the transaction, and if the transaction has confirmed, it is trivial for it to find out about the transaction. Check the wallet software that you are using and make sure that you see the transaction there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The transaction has confirmed on blockchain finally, but somehow my trezor seem have lost the receiving address and this transaction as well. By the way how to check the wallet software that I am using?

Comment: Your Trezor doesn't actually store any transactions (especially ones you receive), and may not even store addresses either. You won't see anything about your transactions or your addresses when you plug in a Trezor to your computer because a) you need software that is running to interact with it and b) the Trezor can't just ask your computer for any data nor does it want to. The wallet software that you are using is whatever software you are using on your computer that lets you get addresses and make transactions. This could be the My Trezor webwallet or a desktop wallet like Electrum.

Comment: Thanks. I use Trezor webwallet, but I does not see the blockchain confirmed transaction. What should I do?

Comment: Contact Trezor's support as they are the only ones that can do anything about their own web wallet service.

Comment: To sum it up are you saying: The address that receives the private key is not stored on the Trezor wallet. But the Trezor wallet is required to access that address?

Comment: Addresses do not receive private keys. Addresses are directly derived from private keys. The private keys are stored in the trezor and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line on this-- Trezor only stores your private keys, not transaction information. To isolate whether the problem is your web wallet or something else, you can just open any other wallet software that can support the Trezor and see if the transaction shows there.

For example, try installing Exodus, Electrum, or even Trezor suite. Any of those applications can be installed on your computer and can work with Trezor Model T (not sure what works with the cheaper model).

Once you have opened a different wallet and your Trezor is connected and signed in with your PIN, the wallet software will extract transaction information from the blockchain associated with the private keys stored on the Trezor.

One other thing I've seen happen that can be confusing is, you may have two accounts with the same name, like there could be a Bitcoin #1 that is a Native Segwit (Bech32) wallet and then also a regular Segwit P2SH wallet with the same name Bitcoin #1. If you happen to have the Bech32 wallet selected, but your bitcoins are in the P2SH wallet, it'll show 0 bitcoins. Click on the P2SH wallet, and you will see your coins. Happened to me ;)